Невозможность бокового передвижения объекта
x - ширина
y - высота
z - длина
α - угол поворота объекта по оси X (плоскость zy)
β - угол поворота объекта по оси Y (плоскость zx)

Система координат локальная, т.е. центр координат соответствует центру объекта.
Направление объекта определяется как
(x: -sin(β)*cos(α), y: sin(α), z: -cos(β)*cos(α))

Применяя к направлению матрицу поворотов получается
(x: -(dx * cos(γ) + dz * sin(γ)), y: -dy * cos(γ), z: -(-dx * sin(γ) + dz * cos(γ)))

где dx, dy, dz - координаты направления объекта, γ - угол поворота.
Таким образом становится возможно движение объекта в стороны, отличные от его направления. Но при α=90° становится невозможным передвижение объекта под углом γ=90° и γ=270°.
Нужно модифицировать формулу
(x: -(dx * cos(γ) + dz * sin(γ)), y: -dy * cos(γ), z: -(-dx * sin(γ) + dz * cos(γ)))

так, чтобы при α=90°, β=0° и γ=90° x был равен 1, а z - 0, а при α=90°, β=90° и γ=90° z был равен 1, а x - 0

Что-то я не очень понимаю, что вы описываете. Ну ладно, Направление объекта - некий направляющий вектор. А что означает γ - угол поворота - поворота вокруг чего? И почему при этом становится возможно движение объекта в стороны?

Суть в том что объект может смотреть в одну сторону, а двигаться в другую. Сторону, в которую движется объект, грубо говоря, по горизонтали, определяет угол γ. По сути это угол отколения от направления объекта. И вот, при α=90°, β=0°/β=90° и γ=90° объект перестает двигаться.

А что мешает для объекта иметь два вектора - направления (куда смотрит) и движения?

Ничего, поэтому направление определяется формулой (x: -sin(β)*cos(α), y: sin(α), z: -cos(β)*cos(α)), а движение - (x: -(dx * cos(γ) + dz * sin(γ)), y: -dy * cos(γ), z: -(-dx * sin(γ) + dz * cos(γ))). Суть проблемы состоит в том что если объект смотрит вниз, а движется вправо, движение прекращается.

А почему прекращается, если это независимые векторы? И мне пока непонятно про гамму, относительно чего вращается вектор направления. Для вращения вектора вокруг произвольной оси  есть формула Родрига (довольно сложная)

Вектор движения зависит от вектора направления, в том то и дело. Так и должно быть. Движение по вертикали соответствует направлению объекта, т.е. если объект смотрит вниз, то и летит вниз. Движение по горизонтали является отколнением от вектора направления под углом γ, т.е. объект может смотреть вперед, а лететь куда-то в бок. Вектор направления вращается относительно самого объекта конечно же.
